# AES Encryption and Decryption not giving proper result

Tags: mysql, encryption, utf-8, aes, collate

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('fmale', '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c') FROM tmp_categorywise_salary_rpt LIMIT 1; 

SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT('þ*Ë(|¸R°¢8Ç©', '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c') as UTF8) FROM tmp_categorywise_salary_rpt LIMIT 1;
```

AES_ENCRYPT is giving me encrypted value as þ*Ë(|¸R°¢8Ç©  but using AES_DECRYPT is giving me null

Expectation : it should give me back non encrypted value as female

Comment: The encrypted value is a binary value. Looking at a binary as text will produce random characters, some of which are likely invisible. Copy-pasting such random garbage text doesn't preserve the actual binary value.

Comment: Use `BLOB` for storing encrypted values, not `TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decrypt the binary value, copying it manually will lead to miss come chars

you can use base64 for printing output like this

```
SELECT TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('fmale', '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c')) FROM tmp_categorywise_salary_rpt LIMIT 1;

SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64('/irLKHwbuBBSGrCiOAzHqQ=='), '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c') AS CHAR);
```

As i have tested in my case

> Encrypted Value : /irLKHwbuBBSGrCiOAzHqQ==

> Decrypted Value : fmale